# Replace accent marks preserving special characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to clean up some string removing accent marks and I do this using the next code:

```
text = ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text)
                       if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')
```

The problem with this piece of code is that also cleans up 'ñ' and 'ç'. I need to preserve this characters to my program to work so, how could I do this?

My first idea was to replace those characters in the original string to something else and after normalise, replace them back, but I ended up with an ugly and time consuming code. Any better idea?

Comment: As a side note, it strikes me that this should be pretty common in Spanish or Portuguese locales, and other locales probably have different rules for what counts as a "basic character" vs. an "accented character" (e.g., German considers `ä` to be an a with umlaut, Swedish considers it a separate letter), and the Unicode locale databases may have this information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Unicode is concerned, the tilde on an `ñ` and the cedilla on a `ç` are accent marks, just like the acute on a `é`.

In particular, the decomposed tilde and cedilla are in the same character class (nonspacing marks) as the decomposed acute. So, if you use that character class to decide what to remove, they'll get removed.

The obvious solution is to code the exceptions manually: drop all characters in the class *except* the ones you want to keep. Like:

```
good_accents = {
    u'\N{COMBINING TILDE}',
    u'\N{COMBINING CEDILLA}'
}

# ...

text = ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text)
                       if (unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'
                           or c in good_accents))
```

If you're on an old enough Python that it doesn't do `\N` escapes (or if I got them wrong and you can't look them up for yourself), you can always use `u'\u0303', u'\u0327'` with a comment instead.

Comment: I really like your solution. Now I feel a little bit embarrassed for mine... xD Thank your for your help.

Comment: Let me ask you a question about your code. I have something like this print(word == 'constança') where word is the same text ('constança') after being normalised. Don't know why, but that code prints False. When I debug using Pycharm the text is the same. Could be this a problem with encoding?

Comment: @DavidMorenoGarcía If one string is in NFKD and the other in NFC, they won't be ==. If that's the problem, you need to normalize all your strings the same way. (In particular, notice that your function will normalize strings to NFKD while removing accents. If your strings are in another normalization before doing this, you'll want to convert them back after removing accents, or convert the others to NFKD.)

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. I changed NFKD to NFKC and now all is working. Thank you again.